# Add SVG Icon Before Accordion Tittle On WordPress and Elementor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I would like to know how to add an SVG Icon Before the Accordion title on Elementor/ WordPress. A different SVG icon for each title. I believe this can be done with CSS. I researched the whole internet but was unable to find anything. Please refer to the attached image as an example and the accordion on this page: https://library.elementor.com/handmade-kids-shop/help-info/

[Accordion Icon Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbkdv.png)

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need custom CSS for this, since Elementor already supports adding Icons to the Toggle Widget titles, as [explained here](https://elementor.com/help/toggle-widget/).

If you don't already have support for SVG files in your media gallery then you can either [add a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/) or use the following code snippet in your `functions.php` :

```
// Allow SVG
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function($data, $file, $filename, $mimes) {

  global $wp_version;
  if ( $wp_version !== '4.7.1' ) {
     return $data;
  }

  $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

  return [
      'ext'             => $filetype['ext'],
      'type'            => $filetype['type'],
      'proper_filename' => $data['proper_filename']
  ];

}, 10, 4 );

function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );

function fix_svg() {
  echo '<style type="text/css">
        .attachment-266x266, .thumbnail img {
             width: 100% !important;
             height: auto !important;
        }
        </style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fix_svg' );
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to add the icons without the code you provided. Now, I would like to know how to add the arrows on the right. I think the arrows are important so the user knows it needs to be clicked. Is there any way I can add those arrows using CSS? thank you so much!